# Filter data where date is within +/-30 days of multiple given dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataset where each observation has a `Date`. Then I have a list of events. I want to filter the dataset and keep observations only if the date is within +/- 30 days of an event. Also, I want to know which event it is closest to.

For example, the main dataset looks like:

```
Product Date
Chicken 2008-09-08
Pork    2008-08-22
Beef    2008-08-15
Rice    2008-07-22
Coke    2008-04-05
Cereal  2008-04-03
Apple   2008-04-02
Banana  2008-04-01
```

It is generated by

```
d = {'Product': ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Cereal', 'Coke', 'Rice', 'Beef', 'Pork', 'Chicken'],
     'Date': ['2008-04-02', '2008-04-01', '2008-04-03', '2008-04-05',
              '2008-07-22', '2008-08-15', '2008-08-22', '2008-09-08']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Then I have a column of events:

```
Date
2008-05-03
2008-07-20
2008-09-01
```

generated by

```
event = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.to_datetime(['2008-05-03', '2008-07-20', '2008-09-01'])})
```

**GOAL (EDITED)**

I want to keep the rows in `df` only if `df['Date']` is within a month of `event['Date']`. For example, the first event occurred on 2008-05-03, so I want to keep observations between 2008-04-03 and 2008-06-03, and also create a new column to tell this observation is closest to the event on 2008-05-03.

```
Product Date        Event
Chicken 2008-09-08  2008-09-01
Pork    2008-08-22  2008-09-01
Beef    2008-08-15  2008-07-20
Rice    2008-07-22  2008-07-20
Coke    2008-04-05  2008-05-03
Cereal  2008-04-03  2008-05-03
```

Comment: What is the common date for you to use , 30 days diff is one month ?  ?

Comment: in your even dates, you have months 5,7 & 9. In the df, you have months 4 to 9, so everything is covered within plus or minus 1 month of event dates

Comment: Ahh yes, I will use 30 days of difference @WeNYoBen.

Comment: Sorry this is not a good example, but hopefully the idea is clear @SH-SF.

Comment: Is it don't-care what happens to dates which fall within +/- 30 days of more than one event? as long as those rows get kept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `numpy` broadcast and assumed within 30 days

```
df[np.any(np.abs(df.Date.values[:,None]-event.Date.values)/np.timedelta64(1,'D')<31,1)]
Out[90]: 
   Product       Date
0  Chicken 2008-09-08
1     Pork 2008-08-22
2     Beef 2008-08-15
3     Rice 2008-07-22
4     Coke 2008-04-05
5   Cereal 2008-04-03
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This also allows me to test other differences like 15 days. Is it possible to create dummies so I can know whether an observation is before or after the event?

Comment: Sorry, I think an easier way to ask is, can I have a column to store the closest event? I have edited the post...

Comment: @Tian check merge_asof

Answer (score 2):

```
event['eDate'] = event.Date    
df = pd.merge_asof(df.sort_values('Date'), event.sort_values('Date'), on="Date", direction='nearest')
df[(df.Date - df.eDate).abs() <= '30 days']
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestion!! This makes a lot of sense. Is there a way to create a column, so I can see which event an observation is closest to? Please see the edited post for details.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer actually works for the additional request.

Answer (score 0):

I would use listcomp with `intervalindex`

```
ms = pd.offsets.MonthOffset(1)
e1 = event.Date - ms
e2 = event.Date + ms
iix = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(e1, e2, closed='both')
df.loc[[any(d in i for i in iix) for d in df.Date]]

Out[93]:
   Product       Date
2   Cereal 2008-04-03
3     Coke 2008-04-05
4     Rice 2008-07-22
5     Beef 2008-08-15
6     Pork 2008-08-22
7  Chicken 2008-09-08
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!! I have two questions... (1) if I want to test other time interval, not 30 days but say 17 days, how can I change `ms`? (2) Is there a way to create a column, so I can see which event an observation is closest to?

Answer (score 0):

If it just months irrespective of dates, this may be useful.

```
rng=[]
for a, b in zip (event['Date'].dt.month-1, event['Date'].dt.month+1):
    rng = rng + list(range(a-1,b+1,1))
df[df['Date'].dt.month.isin(set(rng))]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!! I have two questions... (1) if I want to test other time interval, not 30 days but say 17 days, how can I change `dt.month`? (2) Is there a way to create a column, so I can see which event an observation is closest to?